# Does my spouse's income count the income calculation for the Affordable Care Act? (See details)

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, affordable-care-act

**Scenario:**
I plan to retire before I am eligible for Medicare
My wife is eligible for and plans to sign up for Medicare when I retire
My wife has income from social security
We file our taxes as married/jointly
I'm trying to estimate my healthcare expenses in retirement when I lose my employer plan.

**Question:**
When doing the calculation for the Health insurance subsidy, do I have to count my wife's social security check in my income even though she won't be insuring through ACA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When doing the calculation for the Health insurance subsidy, do I have to count my wife's social security check in my income even though she won't be insuring through ACA?

Yes, what matters is the *household* income, including those who don't need the coverage ([source from healthcare.gov](https://www.healthcare.gov/income-and-household-information/income/)):

> **Whose income to include in your estimate**
>
> For most people, a household consists of the tax filer, their spouse if they have one, and their tax dependents, **including those who don’t need coverage**.